# I have set my GAE firewall to block access from my IPv4, but could not block access

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, firewall, ipv6, ipv4

I have tried to restrict IPv4 access with GAE firewall rules but have been unable to restrict access.
I tried to restrict access with IPv6 instead of IPv4, and that was successful.
In the [Creating App Engine firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/creating-firewalls?hl=en) , IPv4 is listed, but how should I configure it?

Comment: Have you tried to set the Firewall rule in the following way ```gcloud app firewall-rules create PRIORITY --action ALLOW_OR_DENY --source-range IP_RANGE --description DESCRIPTION``` as mentioned in [doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/creating-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules)? If so, are you getting any error message while working with IPv4 address?

Comment: IPv4 is uspported by App Engine firewall. When you mention IPv6 works but IPv4 no, you mean that the same client was blocked when added the IPv6 but not when added the IPv4?

Comment: @Ferregina Pelona
Yes, it is in that state.
If I register my IPv6 from the GAE firewall settings screen, it is blocked, but not my IPv4.

Comment: @Mousumi Roy
Thank you for the help!
Apparently, the cause was that I was communicating via IPv6 due to my internet connection settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone!
It seems that the problem was that I was communicating via IPv6 due to my internet connection settings.
I was able to block it by changing it to communicate over IPv4!